# Can we have a "belongs on [any se site]" option

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign

Is there a possibility to close a question with a reason "belong on [some site]" where some site is replaced by any stack exchange site like math.stackexchange.com or stackoverflow.com

I would suggest doing this like the exact duplicate link. Instead of showing an empty box maybe the top 3 of sites where questions are moved to. And off course after the first close vote, as a suggestion for others the selected site.

An example of question that could be migrated is [How can I get R to stop autocompleting my quotes/parens?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/944/how-can-i-get-r-to-stop-autocompleting-my-quotes-parens)

**ADDITION:**

I realize that the users of this site are experts on whether a question belongs here or not, but not on the question whether it really belongs on the target site. Therefore, there could be on the other site some feature that a 10k user or moderator has to accept the question into the site.

Comment: This is a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

If someone asked their question here - there is probably a reason they chose to post it here than on another StackExchange site.  Preferably that should make that reason clear in their question, but failing that it seems to be incumbent on the community to try to draw those reasons out in the comments.  It is a horrible precedent founded in the worst of socially rough clickish internet behavior to blithly say "you belong over there".  From a user perspective, especially a new user, being told in such an impersonal manner without further interaction that your question is in the wrong place would be very off-putting.  I imagine it is somewhat like calling your bank with a problem and them transferring you to another department who then may very well transfers you back to the first department.  Questions that are getting bounced here to another site are likely cases in the margin, and especially while starting out we should embrace those margin cases.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem that I can see is that this won't work without your addition. And even between the existing Stack Exchange trilogy sites, I feel you need that "accept the question" component. For example, a lot of people vote to move questions about servers to ServerFault from StackOverflow, but ServerFault doesn't like to support individual desktop installations of software, which is what a lot of the questions on SO are.

So the best thing, in my opinion, would just be a general "off-topic" pool of questions. Someplace visible to high rep users and/or mods on every stack exchange. If they feel it belongs on theirs, they can cast an "accept" vote. Once it gets high enough (5 votes to accept to a particular site, perhaps), it gets moved. Questions can also vote to get deleted if they really don't belong anywhere. And also, stats can be collected to see if two StackExchanges are regularly voting to accept the same questions so that their boundaries can be better defined.